# find link in string html with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

i need to find all links in html string only in href
on both cases of double qute("") or single qute('')

example:

```
<a href='text'>
```

or

```
<div href="text">;
```

i came up with

```js
function findHrefValues(str) {
  let hrefs = [];
  let pattern = /href='([^']+)'/g;
  let match = pattern.exec(str);
  if(match && Array.isArray(match)) {
    match.forEach((href)=> {
      if(href) hrefs.push(href);
    });
  }
  return hrefs;
}
```

but its not working well it doesn't recognize double qute.

Comment: please share the html

Comment: [Use an HTML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4665)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code with

`let pattern=/href=('|")([^']+)('|")/g;`

Answer (score 3):

Capture the first `'` or `"` right after `href`, then use a character set that includes anything *but* that same quote character via a backreference, then use the backreference *again* to match the end of the `href`:

```js
const str = `<a href='tex""t1'>
<div href="tex''t2">`;

function findHrefValues(str) {
  const re = /href=(['"])([^\1]+?)\1/g;
  const matches = [];
  let match;
  while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    matches.push(match[2]);
  }
  return matches;
}

console.log(findHrefValues(str));
```

But, if at all possible, don't use a regular expression for this - parse the HTML string instead, possibly with `DOMParser`:

```js
const str = `<a href='text1'>
<div href="text2">`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const hrefs = Array.from(
  doc.querySelectorAll('[href]'),
  element => element.getAttribute('href')
);
console.log(hrefs);
```

Comment: but i use on nodejs

Comment: Node has similar XML parsers, you don't have to use DOMParser: https://www.google.com/search?q=node+domparser